# probability of deck of cards

Tags: probability, playing-cards

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    pick a random index j between 1 and n inclusive;
    swap card[i] and card[j];
}
```

for the above code am trying to find the probability of original `card[k]` winding up in slot `n` is `1/n`? I guess it's `(n-1)/n * 1/(n-1)=1/n`. But can u help me proving this?

Comment: by the way, this is not the way to shuffle a list; it introduces bias. Check out Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm...

Comment: nPr, nCr, my friend - for homework, that is... hehe.

Comment: More math/logic than programming related

Comment: I don't think the pseudo-code at the beginning is enough to make it 'programming-related'.

Comment: How is this not a real question????

Comment: I think it's a real question... even though the solution doesn't require coding, doesn't mean it's not programming related. The OP wants to understand a mathematical property of a piece of code. Wouldn't it be a valid question for someone to ask why the Collection.shuffle() algorithm yields random permutations with equally likely probability? The math is part of understanding the properties of the code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the probability that the k<sup>th</sup> card will end up in slot n is 1/n is because the n<sup>th</sup> iteration *completely* determines what card ends up in slot n! (<--- that's an exclamation point, not a factorial :-).

Think about it. On the last iteration of the loop, you have some random permutation... and the k<sup>th</sup> card is sitting in some slot. The probability it moves into slot n is just the probability that you pick that k<sup>th</sup> card at random. Assuming you pick cards with equally likely probability, that probability is 1/n.

Hope this helps.

-Tom

***UPDATE***

You might be thinking I made a faulty assumption. Namely, you might be wondering... what if the k<sup>th</sup> card can end up in different slots with different probabilities? What if the "random shuffling" isn't really random? This is why only the last iteration matters:

Let p<sub>i</sub> denote the probability that the k<sup>th</sup> card is in slot i on the n-1 iteration (ie - it is in slot i right before the end).

Then the probability that card k ends up in slot n (on the n<sup>th</sup> iteration) is:

(1/n)p<sub>1</sub> + (1/n)p<sub>2</sub> + ... + (1/n)p<sub>n</sub>

But notice we can factor the (1/n), so we have:

(1/n)(p<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>2</sub> + ... + p<sub>n</sub>)

And because these are probabilities, it should be obvious that the sum of the p<sub>i</sub>'s (i = 1 to n) must equal 1. So we are left with just (1/n).

That is just being a bit more formal to show that the randomness of the state of affairs before the n<sup>th</sup> iteration really does not matter.

Comment: Please note, as Mitch Wheat points out, that your algorithm is not a standard "shuffle" algorithm. You should only consider j's that are in between i and n. That will give you a random permutation with equally likely probabliity (incidentally, this is how I have seen the Collections.shuffle() method implemented in java). But that is just a side note... the answer I provided is for the question you asked :-).

Comment: actually going to edit my answer to make it slightly more mathematical...